# Вывести картинку с модели Django

Tags: python, django

Создал табличку в базе данных, вот моя модель:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    img = models.ImageField(blank=True, verbose_name='Images')
    content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Мой views.py:

```
def main(request):
    template = loader.get_template('blogApp/mainPage.html')
    bbs = Blog.objects.order_by('-date')
    context = {'bbs': bbs}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

И html:

```
{% for i in bbs %}
    <h3>{{ i.title }}</h3>
    <img src='{{ i.img.url }}'>
    <h5>{{ i.content }}</h5>
{% endfor %}
```

Добавил в админке новый пост:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но картинку так и не выводит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так и не могу понять в чем проблема. Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: {% load static %} <img src="{% static 'path/to/image.ext' %}"/> попробуйте?

Comment: Это вариант вывода картинки напрямую с пути, а я хотел, чтобы картинку можно было вывести из базы данных (в эту базу я загрузил уже картинку, фото показаны выше). Возможно вы знаете как это сделать?

Comment: посмотрите, как сохранилась картинка в БД? это только имя или относительный путь? посмотрите, что в settings.py прописано в качестве STATIC_URL

Comment: Какой путь у картинки в html? Откройте картинку в админке, она открывается?